# parameter extraction from machine learning

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I'm trying to make expert system with machine learning for image processing

like... for example... I have some perfect image sets and learning engine which trained from those. if i put discolored, weird image in my engine, engine will change the features like color, sharpness, etc...

Normal Machine Learning will give me a answer just image is good or not.

The question is how i get optimal parameter sets(added rgb, parameter for sharpness algorithm's parameter, etc...) not just image is good or not.

Is there any machine learning for extracting parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normal Machine Learning will give me a answer just image is good or not.

False. There is no such thing as 'normal machine learning'. What you have described is a binary classification task, one of tasks withing ML domain.

What you describe leads me to assumption that you want to give an ML algorithm some image and get some quantitative value (some real number) as an output (something you call 'sharpness parameter' etc). This is called a regression task. Read about algorithms for regression to choose the one which should suite you well.

In my opinion, since you are working with images you should try using convolutional neural networks to train on your data and perform a regression on new images which you haven't seen yet. They are really cool in working with images but they are rather 'heavy' from computational point of view.